# 2D geometry: how to check if a point is inside an angle

Tags: geometry, 2d, point

i  have the following geometrical issue in 2D:

i have a point from which i cast an infinite angle (2D-cone) which is given by a direction and an angle. (the point and the direction form a vector and to each side half of the angle forms the 2D-cone)

now i want to check if another point in 2D is inside this cone or outside.

how can this be achieved?
thanks!

Comment: Language shouldn't matter; I believe it's the algorithm the OP is looking for.

Comment: And yes, that's a good point Daniel, what's with the "point in 2D"?

Comment: yes language doesnt matter, it is the algorithm i am looking for. it would even be ok, if you describe it in words. sorry if a cone is 3D, i am not sure what english word to use instead.

Comment: Cone is perfectly OK for 2D too. However you can also use "sector" for 2D.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Calculate the vector from the center of the cone to the query point. Normalize the vector to be of length 1, Take the center vector of the cone and normalize this as well to the length of 1.
Now take the dot product between the vectors. The dot product between two normalized vectors is the cosinus of the angle between them. Take the arccos (`acos` in most languages) of the dot product and you'll get the angle. compare this angle to the cone's angle (half angle in your description). if its lower, then point in question is inside the cone.

This works in 2D and 3D.

Comment: thanks, actually that is what i did all the time, but i just didnt think it is finished, cause i didnt realize where the actual position of the point is taken into account. now it makes sense. thanks!

Comment: Brilliant solution. Note that you can precalculate the "cosine of half the cone angie" and then just use a "if less than" comparison between the result of the dot product and that cosine value, no need for arccos -- as long as the result of the dot product is positive of course, to avoid letting in a point "behind" the cone. This is useful if checking several points against the same cone.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the angle of the direction using arctg of the direction. Substract the origin from the checked point. Calculate its angle (again via arctg of a normalized vector), and check if it lies within angle boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best way is to project the point onto the 2D surface perpendicular to the cones direction. Then you calculate the othogonal distance between that same plane and the point. Finally, you know the width of the cone at that height, so you can see if the point is outside that width.

Answer (score 1):

Let the vector from the point of origin to the specified point makes an angle A with the normal that runs through the center. If the angle A is less than the half angle of the cone it lies inside else outside.